# Cardview onclick event is not working with clickable=true

Tags: java, android, android-cardview

This what I have achieved so far

Image adapter

```java
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    TextView text;
    ImageView imageView;

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.grid_view, null);
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relaGrid);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) rl.findViewById(R.id.chooseImage);
        TextView text = (TextView) rl.findViewById(R.id.chooseText);       
        image.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        text.setText(mThumbTxt[position]);
        Typeface customFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/faruma.ttf");
        text.setTypeface(customFont);
        return rl;
    }

    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.ic_action_gallery, R.drawable.ic_action_gallery,
        R.drawable.ic_action_gallery, R.drawable.ic_action_gallery,
        R.drawable.ic_action_gallery, R.drawable.ic_action_gallery,
        R.drawable.ic_action_gallery, R.drawable.ic_action_gallery
    };

    private String[] mThumbTxt = {
        "Morning", "Evening", "Test deler", "Hepsi", "Test 2", 
        "Test 3", "Test 4", "Test 5"
    };
}
```

View

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/relaGrid"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="6dp"
        android:translationZ="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:onClick="onCardclick"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/chooseImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="85dp">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/chooseText"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chooseImage"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever">
        </TextView>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am trying to get ripple effect on cardview with onclick listener start another intent. but when ripple effect is enabled, onclick event is not working. I just only see ripple effect only. Onclick listener doesn't work. How to achieve both? Please help

Full MainActivity

```java
package com.mycompany.alun;
import android.content.*;
import android.database.sqlite.*;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.support.v7.app.*;
import android.support.v7.widget.*;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.util.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.AdapterView.*;
import java.io.*;

import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.app.*;
import android.support.v4.view.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;
    TextView APP_NAME;
    SearchView searchView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        //Check exists database
        File database = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(DatabaseHelper.DBNAME);
        if(false == database.exists()) {
            mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            //Copy db
            if(copyDatabase(this)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Copy database succes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Copy data error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }

        // Custom title
        TextView textCustomTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.appName);
        Typeface customFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/faruma.ttf");
        textCustomTitle.setTypeface(customFont);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        if (!isTaskRoot()) {
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }

    public void onCardclick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

        switch(position)
        {
            case 0:
                Intent newActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ViewDataActivity.class);
                startActivity(newActivity);
                break;

            case 1:
                Intent newActivity2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MorningActivity.class);
                startActivity(newActivity2);
                break;

            case 2:
                Intent new1Activity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ViewDataActivity.class);
                startActivity(new1Activity);
                break;
            case 3:
                Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.daily_life); // the original file yourimage.jpg i added in resources
                Bitmap dest = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

                String yourText = "My custom Text adding to Image";

                Canvas cs = new Canvas(dest);
                Paint tPaint = new Paint();
                tPaint.setTextSize(35);
                tPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                tPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                cs.drawBitmap(src, 0f, 0f, null);
                float height = tPaint.measureText("yY");
                float width = tPaint.measureText(yourText);
                float x_coord = (src.getWidth() - width)/2;
                cs.drawText(yourText, x_coord, height+15f, tPaint); // 15f is to put space between top edge and the text, if you want to change it, you can
                try {
                    dest.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(new File("/sdcard/ImageAfterAddingText.jpg")));
                    // dest is Bitmap, if you want to preview the final image, you can display it on screen also before saving
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                new CustomToast(getApplicationContext(), getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.add_favorites));
                break;
            case 5:
                Intent searchActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SearchActivity.class);
                startActivity(searchActivity);
                break;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrong Input", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.nav_menu, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public void getInput(String searchText)
    {
        Intent in = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);
        in.putExtra("SEARCH", searchText);
        startActivity(in);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_favorites) {
            Intent newActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,FavoritesActivity.class);
            startActivity(newActivity);
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_search) {
            Intent newActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SearchActivity.class);
            startActivity(newActivity);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private boolean copyDatabase(Context context) {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(DatabaseHelper.DBNAME);
            String outFileName = DatabaseHelper.DBLOCATION + DatabaseHelper.DBNAME;
            Log.d("ViewDataActivity", "outFileName : "+outFileName);
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            byte[]buff = new byte[1024];
            int length = 0;
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buff)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buff, 0, length);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            Log.w("ViewDataActivity","DB copied");
            return true;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you should be returning view and not rl(RelativeLayout) in your getView method in your adapter

Comment: that doesn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside adapter method getView()

```
CardView cardView = view.findViewById(R.id.card_view_id_from_grid_view)
cardView.setOnClickListener(...)
```

**EDIT**

```
interface CustomClick{
     void onClick(int position)
}

private CustomClick customClick;

// Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c, CustomClick customClick) {
        mContext = c;
        this.customClick = customClick;

    }

cardView.setOnClickListener(view -> customClick.onClick(position))
```

MainActivity implements CustomClick

```
new ImageAdapter(this, this)
```

Comment: How to switch position like

Comment: int position from getView() is position of the item in the list. You can create switch inside click listener implemented inside getView() with position param. You can also build interface to pass position and implement it in MainActivity

Comment: Thank you i fixed the problem 

Answer (score 1):

First of all assign a specific ID to it.

```
android:id="@+id/btnCardView"
```

And yes have it clickable="true".
Then the usual work, go to that respective activity.
Then initialise your card view there.

```
private CardView cardview;
cardview = findViewById(R.id.btnCardView);

btnCardView.setOnClickListener(new ....) {
//Your function here
}
```

My intention is to say add the onClickListener to the CardView itself instead of the Relative layout in it.

And just a note that ripple effect won't work on older versions of Android.

Comment: It's an adapter so I don't know how to do that.. MainActivity has another layout.